# How to receive message from 'any' channel in PROMELA/SPIN

Tags: spin

I'm modeling an algorithm in Spin.
I have a process that has several channels and at some point, I know a message is going to come but don't know from which channel. So want to wait (block) the process until it a message comes from any of the channels. how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need Promela's if construct (see http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/if.html).

In the process you're referring to, you probably need the following:

```
byte var;
if
:: ch1?var -> skip
:: ch2?var -> skip
:: ch3?var -> skip
fi
```

If none of the channels have anything on them, then "the selection construct as a whole blocks" (quoting the manual), which is exactly the behaviour you want.

To quote the relevant part of the manual more fully:
"An option [each of the :: lines] can be selected for execution only when its guard statement is executable [the guard statement is the part before the ->]. If more than one guard statement is executable, one of them will be selected non-deterministically. If none of the guards are executable, the selection construct as a whole blocks."

By the way, I haven't syntax checked or simulated the above in Spin. Hopefully it's right. I'm quite new to Promela and Spin myself.

Comment: Note that the '-> skip' is not necessary.

Comment: and what if number of channels is n? meaning there is a define value in the start.. and someone may change it's value... ? in this way you will have to modify your code... is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your number of channels variable without having to change the implementation of the send and receive parts, you might use the approach of the following producer-consumer example:

```
#define NUMCHAN 4

chan channels[NUMCHAN];

init {
    chan ch1 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch2 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch3 = [1] of { byte };
    chan ch4 = [1] of { byte };

    channels[0] = ch1;
    channels[1] = ch2;
    channels[2] = ch3;
    channels[3] = ch4;
    // Add further channels above, in
    // accordance with NUMCHAN

    // First let the producer write
    // something, then start the consumer
    run producer();
    atomic { _nr_pr == 1 ->
        run consumer();
    }
}

proctype consumer() {
    byte var, i;
    chan theChan;

    i = 0;
    do
        :: i == NUMCHAN -> break
        :: else ->
             theChan = channels[i];
             if
               :: skip // non-deterministic skip
               :: nempty(theChan) ->
                  theChan ? var;
                  printf("Read value %d from channel %d\n", var, i+1)
             fi;
             i++
    od
}

proctype producer() {
    byte var, i;
    chan theChan;

    i = 0;
    do
        :: i == NUMCHAN -> break
        :: else ->
             theChan = channels[i];
             if
               :: skip;
               :: theChan ! 1;
                  printf("Write value 1 to channel %d\n", i+1)
             fi;
             i++
    od
}
```

The `do` loop in the consumer process non-deterministically chooses an index between `0` and `NUMCHAN-1` and reads from the respective channel, if there is something to read, else this channel is always skipped. Naturally, during a simulation with Spin the probability to read from channel `NUMCHAN` is much smaller than that of channel `0`, but this does not make any difference in model checking, where any possible path is explored.